# How to replace xml attribute value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a pure xml in a textarea in jsp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <OTA_RQ Version="14.2" xmlns="http://www.opentrvl.org/OTA/2003/05">
  <Reference Type="14" ID="res_no" />
</OTA_RQ>
```

On the fly I want to change `res_no` to `WA-12345` using jquery or javascript. I tried replace method, but it's look like jquery is not treating the xml as a simple string.

These are the things I tried to no help:

`var strNewString = $("#myTextArea").html().replace(/\'res_no'/g,'WA-12345`');

..

```
commandReplaced.replace("res_no", 'WA-12345');
```

..

```
j = $("#myTextArea").val());
j.find('Reference').attr('ID', 'WA-12345');
```

Comment: Can you share you unsuccessful attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting the xml in a textarea and replaced the `res_no` with `WA-12345`. It worked correctly,

You can see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BXWN6/2/)